# Parse raw string HTML to HtmlDivision instance (HtmlUnit)

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to cast a simple raw HTML string (coming from an AJAX call) to HtmlDivision instance using [HtmlUnit](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/) library

```
String div = "<div ... /div>"

HtmlDivision div = (HtmlDivision) div;
```

I tried a default cast in Java and also looked in official documentation but until now no success.

Answer (score 1):

I swap to [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) because have a good parser for raw strings.

Comment: This does not quite answer the implied *How do I assign to an `HtmlDivision` what's in a raw HTML "div string"?*

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample in the FAQ - see https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/faq.html#HowToParseHtmlString

Comment: Remember *please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link*?